# Calculus: Bending moment given by $M=Wx(l-x)/2$. Find maximum bending moment

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

I have been given the equation $M=Wx\frac{l-x}{2}$

- $M$ is the Bending moment
- $W$ is the Weight per unit length
- $L$ is the Length
- $x$ is the distance of load from one end.

I have found the derivative $f(x) = \frac{Wl}{2} - Wx$

I am unsure where to go from here. The examples which I have found online don't give three unknowns.

From what I understand I need to make this equation equal zero and then solve for x to determine my maximum but how would I solve for $x$ with 3 unknowns?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, please refer to this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

You took the derivative and now you have to set it equal to zero. That allows you to solve it for $x$. It follows that $W$ is independent here for your solution, $x$ will depend on $l$ only.
Alternatively your formula is of quadratic nature, a parabola that opens down. So you can find the desired value of $x$ by using the well known formula $-b/(2a)$ from your algebra class to find the same result. Side note, there is only one unknown which is the $x$. The other letters are assumed fixed parameters. Either way, you should find $x=l/2$ but I want you to verify that.

Comment: I understand. Where x=1/2, I now implement that into the original equation and simplify to get the equation for the maximum bending moment.

Comment: It is important to note that the maximum could, in general, occur at the boundaries (but doesn't in this case).

Comment: @JPMcCarthy Yes from a Calculus perspective that is correct. I didn't think of it in this particular case though